# How can I make an ego graph of a given vertex (igrap)

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I'm trying to make and plot an ego network of a given vertex in a larger network.
I get my network from a csv file containing a weighted edge list:

```
art<-read.csv(file.choose("art.csv"))
g_art<-graph.data.frame(art)
```

Then, I use the function make_ego_graph as follows:

```
g_ego_art<-make_ego_graph(g_art, order=2, nodes = "PLAZA")
```

Then I try to plot the vertex PLAZA's ego netrwork and I get this error:

```
plot(g_ego_art)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

Any help, please?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Help us to help you by providing a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and do read also [these](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines about how to ask a good question here. The more clear and easy to understand the question is the more you will receive help.

Comment: `make_ego_graph` returns a list of graphs, not a graph.

Comment: so, I guess the first element in the list is my ego graph

Answer (score 3):

`make_ego_graph` will return a list of ego network... if u want to see the first one, simply `plot(g_ego_art[[1]])`

Comment: @Petter Friberg, Thanks for the comment, How can I show all list nodes in one graph? Thanks!